# Minimal number of steps to construct $\cos(2 \pi /n)$

Tags: geometry, optimization, geometric-construction

My question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456792/minimal-number-of-moves-to-construct-the-challenges-circle-packings-and-regular?rq=1) previous one. I was wondering what is the minimal number of steps $S(a)$ to construct a number $a \in \mathbb R$ that is constructible (as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number)).

For instance, I could construct $\sqrt 2$ in 6 steps (is it possible to do better ?). By "step", I mean either drawing a circle when the compass is placed, or drawing a line when the straightedge is placed.

Following the ideas found on [this](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~sqrt/cons/constructions.html) page (see "Best Known Constructions"), here is a construction of $\cos(2\pi / 5)$ in 10 steps (if $|P_1P_2| = 1$, then this is the red segment $P_2A$) :

[image: Pentagon]

Is it possible to do better ? What are some interesting bounds on the minimal number of steps to construct $x_n = \cos(2 \pi / n)$, with $n=2^kF_1 \cdots F_r$ and $F_i$ are distinct Fermat primes ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: the simplest bound is the following  : since each field extension is of degree 2 you cannot construct a numer of degree $2^n$ in less than $n$ steps.

Comment: @Renart : thank you ! This is what I thought. More generally, do you think that the minimal number S(x) of steps to construct $x$ is bounded from below by $\log_2(\deg_{\mathbb Q}(x))$ ?

Comment: If $x$ is constructible then its degree over $\mathbf Q$ is a power of $2$, So yes.